# Dynamic server sharding

Tags: load-balancing

Suppose I want to add more servers to my backends realtime, what is the standard way to get my http server to update its internal rpc data structure so it load balances on the new backends.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the server you're using as a load balancer.  [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) supports the HUP signal to reload its configuration file, allowing you to add or remove backends.  [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) does load balancing and has a web GUI for updating configuration. [HA Proxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) supports updating configuration without having to shutdown and restart.

What server are you using?

Comment: Well what if I have a three tier architecture with application servers between the httpserver and backends?

Comment: Are you asking about adding into the 3rd tier?  What is the 'backend'?  Depending on what it is you may be able to put it behind a load balancer (eg: if it's a service); if it's a DB you may be able to use HA JDBC or another proxy.  What I do (currently) is update the configuration of my middle tier systems by taking them out of rotation 1 at a time, updating the config (adding the additional back-ends and then restarting) and putting them back into rotation in the front-end LB.  This is the same process I use for doing rolling releases.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: One would think that there should be a generic solution that is software independent that works without tying oneself to and depending on specific behavior of Nginx, Cherokee, etc. Having a solution that is independent of the software used strikes me as the correct software engineering solution.